# JPA not clearing a Set iterator when saving in OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence, javax

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this domain class:

```
    Entity
    @DiscriminatorValue("sebloc")
    public class SeblocDevice extends Device {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public SeblocDevice() {
            super();
        }

        public SeblocDevice(String deviceKey, String devicePAC) {
            super(deviceKey, devicePAC);
        }

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<DeviceDriver> driverDevices = new HashSet<>();

        public Set<DeviceDriver> getDriverDevices() {
            return driverDevices;
        }

        public void setDriverDevices(Set<DeviceDriver> driverDevices) {
            this.driverDevices = driverDevices;
        }

      public void clearDriverDevices()  {
    for (DeviceDriver deviceDriver : deviceDrivers) {
        deviceDriver.setDriver(null);
        driverDevices.remove(deviceDriver);
    }

public void removeDriverDevice(DeviceDriver deviceDriver)  {
    deviceDriver.setDriver(null);
    driverDevices.remove(deviceDriver);
}
}
    ...
    }
```

and this other domain object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_device_driver")
public class DeviceDriver implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DeviceDriver() {

    }

    public DeviceDriver (SeblocDevice device, Driver driver) {
        this.device = device;
        this.driver = driver;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_id")
    private SeblocDevice device;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
    private Driver driver;

    public SeblocDevice getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(SeblocDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public Driver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(Driver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

and this JUnit test, where in the last test I was excepting 1 driver but I got 2 (clear all the drivers, and add 1)

```
    @Test
    public void testUpdateAuthorizedDriver() {

        SeblocDevice seblocDevice = (SeblocDevice) deviceService.findById((long)1);

        assertEquals (1,seblocDevice.getDriverDevices().size());

        Driver authorizedDriver   = (Driver) driverService.findById((long)2);

        DeviceDriver dd  = new DeviceDriver (seblocDevice, authorizedDriver);

DeviceDriver ddToRemove = seblocDevice.getDeviceDrivers().iterator().next();

        seblocDevice.removeDriverDevice(ddToRemove);

        seblocDevice.clearDriverDevices()
        seblocDevice.getDriverDevices().clear();
        seblocDevice.getDriverDevices().add(dd);

        deviceService.save(seblocDevice);

        assertEquals (1,    seblocDevice.getDriverDevices().size());
        assertEquals (1,    Iterators.size(deviceService.findSeblocDeviceAll().iterator()));

        SeblocDevice seblocDeviceRetrieved  = deviceService.findSeblocDeviceAll().iterator().next();

        assertEquals (1,    seblocDeviceRetrieved.getDriverDevices().size());

    }
```

I also tried to create a method in the service level

```
public interface DeviceDriverRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceDriver, Long> {

}
@Transactional
     public SeblocDevice cleanDrivers (SeblocDevice seblocDevice) {
         deviceDriverRepository.delete(seblocDevice.getDeviceDrivers());
     seblocDevice.getDeviceDrivers().clear();
     seblocDevice.setDeviceDrivers(null);
     return seblocDeviceRepository.save (seblocDevice);
     }
```

and then `deviceService.cleanDrivers(seblocDevice);`

but the drivers appears again

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the type of the `driverService` field?

Comment: Why would you expect one driver? You created an additional driver associated to `SeblocDevice` and never removed the one that already existed... I'm guessing you expected the existing `DeviceDriver` to be no longer associated to `SeblocDevice` after calling `seblocDevice.getDriverDevices().clear()` but for that to happen, `SeblocDevice.driverDevices` would need to be the *owning* side of the association, which it isn't.

Comment: When you work with bidirectional mapping you must add or remove items at both ends. And your  `deviceService.save` method must be annotated with `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crizzis is right you have to set device to null.

The best way to keep a bidirectional association consistent is to create convenience methods like:

```
public void addDriverDevice(DeviceDriver deviceDriver)  {
    deviceDriver.setDriver(deviceDriver);
    driverDevices.add(deviceDriver);
}

public void removeDriverDevice(DeviceDriver deviceDriver)  {
    deviceDriver.setDriver(null);
    driverDevices.remove(deviceDriver);
}
```

And if you want to clear all

```
public void clearDriverDevices()  {
    for (DeviceDriver deviceDriver : deviceDrivers) {
        deviceDriver.setDriver(null);
        driverDevices.remove(deviceDriver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work as you expect, you need to add the `orphanRemoval=true` parameter in  `@OneToMany` relationship in `SeblocDevice.driverDevices` attribute as shown below:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<DeviceDriver> driverDevices = new HashSet<>();
```

To clearly understand the JPA mapping. You need to keep in mind that in a relationship, there is always the owner side.
For example, in an `@OneToMany` vs. `@ManyToOne` relationship, `@ManyToOne` is the owner because it has the reference to the other entity.

Basically the Entity Manager only cares for changes on the owner side, ie if you invoke `DeviceDriver.setDevice(null)`, the removal will be performed. But the opposite 
 (`SeblocDevice.getDriverDevices().clear()`) is not true.

For this reason, there is the **orphanRemoval** parameter, which is self explanatory. When this parameter is assigned, the Entity Manager will now control the elements of the collection as an owner, and a `SeblocDevice.getDriverDevices().clear()` will remove the DeviceDrivers in database that are not in the `SeblocDevice.getDriverDevices` collection, even though `DeviceDriver.device` is not null.

Comment: I've tried with the same result, definitely I am doing something wrong I don't see